# Is there a .NET library for Kinect to develop Kinect application for PC (not XBOX)

Tags: .net, kinect

Is there a .NET library for Kinect to develop Kinect application for PC (not XBOX)? Library doesn't need to be official. (*AFAIK MS won't release a library for PC anyway*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try [NKinect](http://nkinect.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 8):

Update: Kinect SDK is out now.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has promised they will *eventually* release drivers and an SDK for the Kinect. Accorrding to [this link](http://www.reghardware.com/2011/01/18/kinect_support_for_windows/), that may be sooner rather then later.

Otherwise, check out the [Openkinect mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/openkinect/) and [wiki](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page). They will be up to date on everything relating to development for the Kinect.

Answer (score 2):

[librfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) from OpenKinect has a C# wrapper

Answer (score 1):

[OpenNI + Nite](http://www.openni.org/) => C#

[KinectSDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/) => ".Net"

You can find a comparison here: [Official Kinect SDK vs. Open-source alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706448/official-kinect-sdk-vs-open-source-alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.openni.org/ along with Primesense have released a driver, middleware, and a collection of samples for a variety of languages that will help you get started.

We've written up a small document on how to get it up and running easily here: 
http://beta.innovation.rit.edu/csi2/main/blog/kTouch/115

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Just in from ZD.NET "Microsoft readies hobbyist Kinect development kit; promises commercial version later" [link](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-readies-hobbyist-kinect-development-kit-promises-commercial-version-later/8752)

**Prior Post**

The makers/OEM of the Kinect is PrimeSense.  They make both the kinect and an independent [devkit](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/12/10/primesense-releases-open-source-drivers-middleware-for-kinect/).  They recently released open source drivers that are compatible with both XBox's Kinect and the smaller DevKit.  You might as well get the drivers straight from the source.  I'm not sure what value a 3rd party library (openKinect) will offer.

Get the unified Kinect and DevKit drivers here: http://www.openni.org/  Windows and Unix support is available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use NUI. I used it and it's one of the best. Look at http://codelaboratories.com/nui and http://nkinect.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Kinect for Windows SDK version 1 is now also available.