# Kinect Game on Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, kinect

I have a project that requires Microsoft Kinect (Windows Version), and also requires running on a Mac and on Windows.

Which platform does everybody think would be the best choice for this? I am developing on a PC. So what would be best in terms of the smoothest transfer to the Mac, and also up to date?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706448/official-kinect-sdk-vs-open-source-alternatives/7706548#7706548 , a bit old and a lot has happend since, but if the information is still correct (and I beleive it is but I have put my own development at hold) then OpenKinect is your friend. The official SDK only ran at Win 7 at the time of the post.'

Comment: We now also have a sister site dedicated to [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RegDwight Not necessarily game development...