# Opening Kinect datasets and/or SDK Samples

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am very new to Kinect programming and am tasked to understand several methods for 3D point cloud stitching using Kinect and OpenCV. While waiting for the Kinect sensor to be shipped over, I am trying to run the SDK samples on some data sets.

I am really clueless as to where to start now, so I downloaded some datasets [here](http://rgbd-dataset.cs.washington.edu/dataset.html), and do not understand how I am supposed to view/parse these datasets. I tried running the Kinect SDK Samples **(DepthBasic-D2D)** in **Visual Studio** but the only thing that appears is a white screen with a screenshot button.

There seems to be very little documentation with regards to how all these things work, so I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the right resources on how to **obtain and parse depth maps**, or how to **get the SDK Samples work**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Point Cloud Library (or PCL)](http://pointclouds.org/) it is a good starting point to handle point cloud data obtained using Kinect and [OpenNI driver](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI).

OpenNI is, among other things, an open-source software that provides an API to communicate with vision and audio sensor devices (such as the Kinect). Using OpenNI you can access to the raw data acquired with your Kinect and use it as a input for your PCL software that can process the data. In other words, OpenNI is an alternative to the official KinectSDK, compatible with many more devices, and with great support and tutorials!

There are plenty of tutorials out there like [this](http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_1:_Installing_and_testing), [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php) and [these](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/).

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706448/official-kinect-sdk-vs-open-source-alternatives) is highly related.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Is it possible for you to explain to me what OpenNI actually does?